# Cannot convert value type "" to expected argument 'UInt64'

Tags: swift, swift3

I used this piece of code right after converting from Swift 2 to Swift 3, and this error message came up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am very new to Swift 3.

```
func checkIfCorrect (_ buttonPressed:Int) {
    if buttonPressed == playlist[numberOfTaps] {
        if numberOfTaps == playlist.count - 1 { // we have arrived at the last item of the playlist

            let time = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: DispatchTime.now()) + Double(Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: { 
                    self.nextRound()
            })

            return
        }

        numberOfTaps += 1
    }else{ // GAME OVER
        resetGame()
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the full error? Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 3):

Where you have this:

```
let time = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: DispatchTime.now()) + Double(Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
```

put this:

```
let time = DispatchTime.now() + 1.0 // or however long you want the delay to be
```